# How do I extend my app main.xml so it shows my "stuff" off the bottom of the display?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

I have a lot of input boxes on my main activity in android app. The trouble I'm having is I can't for the life of me find how to extend the view (scroll) down to the boxes that are off the bottom of the page.

I tried scrollview but this simply locked up my app.

Last TextView doesn't display

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
     />

<EditText

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



<EditText

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/company"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/when"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/what_now"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this might don't help you, but you should rethink the approach of your activity because users are usually lazy and doesn't perceive well the need for scrolling.

Comment: im making the app for myself.. or trying to.. all i want to do is create a form with some info i enter that stores in a database that i can look through.. basically logging things i do on a weekly basis.

Comment: Is it necessary to log so many thing in the same page? can't you split the inputs in 2 or more activities and follow a installer-like approach (next-next-next-save) approach?

Comment: I think the layout editor shows all the items anyway. but my hack used to be to set the visibility of the top views to gone, so the lower ones would show. I'm considering you are having trouble ading the views by layout editor btw.

Comment: i suppose i could split them up but that would be the long road as i preffer to input it all in one page, then view the results in another activity in a list.. i may well be talking rubbish here but thats how id preffer it. the app is basicallya refference for me to look back on

Comment: no the bottom textview doesnt diplay on my galaxy s2.. like i cant scroll down to it.. im pressumed it would show by default when i scroll but it doesnt so thats why im asking lol

Comment: Thinking about it.. the "next-next-next-save" approach is probably the best idea lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrollview` should work.  Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/setupScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        your stuff here....

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the outermost `LinearLayout`

Comment: Perhaps not, but even so, this still works for me.  I have a layout almost exactly like the asker's.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just remember that every time you nest elements, you eat up memory.

Comment: Ah yes.  @jamie, be aware of this.  Perhaps Aleks's answer would be best to try first.

Comment: Ahh the scrollview worked.. except for the small v in the last </Scrollview> lol.. had me baffled for a bit.. thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your LinearLayout inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
             />

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



        <EditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/company"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/when"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/what_now"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```